# Promoting an Elasticsearch replica node into a Master

Tags: elasticsearch

We're running a very small local 2 node Elasticsearch (7.8.0) cluster (one machine is master/data,
the other was for the replicas) on VMs on our network

Alas, we found that our master machine had rolled itself back by 2 months. At first, I thought that the replica had synchronised itself back 2 months too, but checking closer, it has stopped communicating entirely with the master

I can ping the root of the replica to get the `tagline: "You Know, for Search"` json, but when I do a GET to `_cat/indices/`, I get:

```
{
error: {
root_cause: [
{
type: "master_not_discovered_exception",
reason: null
}
],
type: "master_not_discovered_exception",
reason: null
},
status: 503
}
```

I've updated the replica `elasticsearch.yml` to change the cluster name and to remove any mention of the master node in an attempt to get it run standalone and so we can recover our last 2 months, but no luck

any ideas please?

---

Unbelievable - I've found what the problem was. When the master machine rolled back, it was to a time before we changed the default `cluster.name` setting from `elasticsearch`.  I updated it back to what it should have been, everything synchronised (just), everybody happy

Comment: which elasticsearch version you are using?

Comment: good point - 7.8.0 (and updating)

Comment: please share elasticsearch logs of two server.

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearhc 7.8 you cannot easily change or delete a master node from cluster or making a DataNode standalone cluster.

according to documention(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/node-tool.html) you should use elasticsearch-node detach-cluster command .

```
ES_CONF=/etc/elasticsearch /usr/share/bin/elasticsearch-node detach-cluster
```

Comment: Hi Hamid - sorry for the delay. No - I'm still getting the same error ..

Comment: we didn't need to - just needed to get the cluster name back in sync after the rollback (facepalm ...)